# How to make Android Studio automatically create Vector drawable from svg files?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, svg

I am using Android Studio 2.0 and am targeting SDK verion 21 which supports vector images.

I add the .svg file from New->Vector Asset and it generates a drawable from it (.xml).

The problem is that when i change the .svg (in a vector graphics editor) then the .xml is not automatically updated inside the Studio. How to make it automatically update the generated .xml files if the .svg changes?

Regards!

Comment: `create xml from svg files` doesn't mean anything. SVG **is** (nothing but) XML.

Comment: Raw svg does not seem to be acceptable for Android Studio. Therefore i have to generate the drawable.xml from it via the "Vector Asset" dialog.

Comment: If I correctly interpret your question, you are actually asking: `How do I get a VectorDrawable from an SVG file?`.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant, just did not figure out how to properly call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can't.

There's no official way to auto-generate and I never found any 3rd party tool to automatic do the conversion.

But there're several other tools for such conversion that might be easier than using Android Studio.:

- Sketch plugin to export directly to XML: https://github.com/jacobmoncur/SketchVectorDrawable
- Online converter and offline batch converter: https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter
- IntelliJ plugin: https://github.com/misakuo/svgtoandroid/blob/master/readme_en.md

Comment: I've found a gradle plugin by trello to do exactly that. https://github.com/trello/victor. You can give it a try, but it was awful for majority of my svgs (optimized for vector drawable - Android Studio import worked for them).

Comment: Since Android Studio 3.4 you can use Resource Manager. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811776/2531709

Answer (score 47):

The answer is: you can!!

And it is very easy! Just click right button on folder(drawable for ex.) and choose:

[image]

then choose:

[image]

and your got it!

(There are some restrictions: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#PSD)

Comment: Life saver tip!! But it doesn't support <text> tags in svg

Comment: What if I have 100500 svg files? Is it possible to add whole directory?

Comment: Using the Android Studio 3.4 or higher it is possible to add a whole directory to convert all files in this directory. To do it You can use the Resource Manager: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager Tools -> Resource Manager -> + -> Import Drawables

Answer (score 3):

Using the Android Studio 3.4 or higher it is possible to add a whole directory to convert all files in this directory. To do it You can use the **Resource Manager**: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager
`Tools -> Resource Manager -> + -> Import Drawables`

[image]